# Building android H264 decoder using OpenMAX AL

Tags: android, android-ndk, hardware-acceleration, openmax

I am trying to develope an H264 hardware accelerated video decoder using OpenMAX AL API. But [this](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/openmaxal/) documents states that -

> The only supported way to supply multimedia content is via an MPEG-2
>   transport stream.

But according to  Wikipedia, `MPEG-2` is `H262` and older less advanced version of `H264`. So should decoding `H264` work?

Also, the above documents states that -

> The major feature is the ability to play an MPEG-2 transport stream
>   containing a single program stream made up of one H.264 video
>   elementary stream and one AAC audio elementary stream.

So what's the fact here? Would I able to decode H264 Baseline Annex B stream using OpenMax AL? Or do I need to approach with `OpenMax IL` or `stagefright`?

Comment: _"The only supported way to supply multimedia content is via an MPEG-2 transport stream. But according to Wikipedia, MPEG-2 is H262 and older less advanced version of H264"_ You seem to be mixing up different concepts here. H.262 is a _video compression_ standard. An MPEG-2 transport stream is a _container format_.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for your answer. So it should work with `H.264` stream, right? Note that, I am not streaming any media container, its RTSP from any camera/capturer. Well, and I am not encoding with OpenMax also, just decoding.

Comment: What are you trying to do that isn't supported by the public APIs? Why not use MediaCodec?

Comment: @fadden Because MediaCodec is Java API and I need to interfacing with jni which will be slower/out of sync with audio due to JNI calls are expensive (probable reason may be).

Comment: OpenMax AL has been exposed from Android 14 and now a public API of native layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, OpenMax AL only supports the decoding of MPEG-2 transport stream via a buffer queue. This rules out passing raw h264 NALUs or other media formats for that matter.